# How to jump a line in a file using C++

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling

I want to increase the second line in my file, but I can't. How can I do it?

Here is my file content

```
0
0
```

I want to increase the second '0' by 1. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("file1.txt");

    std::string line;
    getline(file, line);
    getline(file, line);
    int a = std::stoi(line);
    ++a;
    line = std::to_string(a);
    file.close();

    file.open("file1.txt");
    std::string line1;
    getline(file, line1);
    getline(file, line1);
    file << line;
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying too hard. This is the easy way

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file_in("file1.txt");
    int a, b;
    file_in >> a >> b;
    file_in.close();
    ++b;
    std::ofstream file_out("file1.txt");
    file_out << a << '\n' << b << '\n';
    file_out.close();
}
```

Read the **whole** contents of the file. Make the modification needed. Write the **whole** contents of the file.

Doing partial updates (as you are trying) can be done, but it's tricky.

Comment: And in general partial updates *cannot* be done *at all*. Not in C++, not in any other language. They only work under specific conditions (no change to the length of the modified section). Any change that leads to a modification of the data requires rewriting the entire file contents starting at the location of the first change. In OP's case, a partial update wouldn't work as soon as the number on the second line spills over into the next order of magnitude and there are more lines after the second.